# Problems with saving data with single quote ' in the query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have an asp.net project in which I am getting an error while saving data.I have a text box for school name, most school names get saved but if I have a school name like St.Xavier's, it creates a problem during the execution of the insert query.This happens due to the presence of a single quote in the text.As a result the eventual query that I get is:

```
Insert Into tblSchool(SchoolName, CreatedBy, CreatedOn) 
values('St.Xavier's',1,'2014-6-13     13:14:16')
```

How can I save data with single quotes in the text? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead. You will be a happy person after.

Comment: It is 2014. How are there still people who use concatenation to create SQL? Isn't "use parameters" a "lessons 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4" when touching data?

Comment: In future, please provide the code that's causing a problem. I've *guessed* at what your code looks like, but I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't shown your code, but I *strongly suspect* that you've got code such as:

```
// Bad code!
String sql = "Insert Into tblSchool(SchoolName, CreatedBy, CreatedOn) "
           + "values('" + name + "'," + creator + ",'" + date +"')";
```

**Don't do that.** It's hard to read, error-prone in terms of conversions, and vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Instead, you should use parameterized SQL. Something like:

```
String sql = "Insert Into tblSchool(SchoolName, CreatedBy, CreatedOn) "
           + "values(@Name, @CreatedBy, @CreatedOn)";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = creator;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;

    int results = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ...
}
```

See the [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for more details.

Comment: and for the really <s>lazy</s> pragmatic, "dapper" makes this just: `connection.Execute("Insert Into tblSchool(SchoolName, CreatedBy, CreatedOn) values (@name, @creator, @date)", new { name, creator, date });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with [bind parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `SqlCommand`. Anything else is bound to fail.

Answer (score -3):

You need to quote the ' with another '. I.e.:

```
values('St.Xavier''s',1,'2014-6-13     13:14:16')
```

Comment: While that might work, it's leading the OP down a dark path of manual escaping. Parameterized SQL is a *far, far* better solution.

Comment: it might lead op to dark path but he is trying to find an immediate solution hence i think this answer is precise and valid.

Comment: @Ratna: So you'd be happy for the OP to continue with code which is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and goodness knows what other problems? This answer doesn't even *mention* that including values directly within SQL is a bad idea. Sometimes, an existing path is simply so bad that you should turn back rather than taking a slight diversion which just throws you over the cliff successfully.